# Async TcpClient disables the Internet after 30 seconds of sending data

Tags: c#, asynchronous, networking, tcpclient

I wrote a small library for sending simple HTTP requests for the sake of interest based on asynchronous TcpClient. I went to the tests and faced a problem. When I run about 200 tasks to send a request, the program sends and receives data in about 30 seconds, after which Internet access is cut off and requests are stopped.

```
        var tasks = new List<Task>();

        for (int i = 0; i < 200; i++)
        {
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    var message = new GetHttpMessage("www.stackoverflow.com")
                    {
                        Headers = { {"User-agent","Test-agent-1"} }
                    };

                    var req = new Request(message);
                    var resp = await req.SendAsync();
                }
            }));
        }

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

The Internet disappears completely, the browser does not work too. Having decided to look at the activity of the network, I saw that at the beginning of work the connections actively appear and disappear, and at the time of stopping they simply hang in a certain state.

[Screenshot of network activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAJZP.png)

I use a router, maybe the problem is in it?

Comment: This is just a guess but I bet your router is dieing under the load. Around 200 concurrent connections is what I have seen most SOHO routers top out at.

Comment: Perhaps your connections are not getting disposed correctly between requests. Try wrapping your code in a `using` statement like so: `using (var req = new Request(message)) { var resp = await.reqSendAsync(); }`

Comment: @ChristopherLake my code there is just a simple sample. I have used Using but its didnt help

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Is there any way to make sure of this?

Comment: `while (true)` - is that right?

Comment: @500-InternalServerError yes, i used it for simulate a program activity

Comment: @Z-z-z-a-pBitch if you have another computer on the network and that also can't get on the internet then it is the router not your computer that is having a problem.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain oh thx. I have tested and my second pc has no internet too. So the problem with router. Maybe there are some settings that allow to fix it or do I need to buy a better router?)